# Why does the image not show up on the screen when I blit it?

Tags: python, pygame, blit

Using Python (and Pygame), I have been creating a short one-screen game and I code each part in a different window. In my Home Screen, when I blit the play button onto the screen, it doesn't appear. I am new to Python and Pygame. This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1352,638))
pygame.display.set_caption("Termination: Part 1")
bg = True
playButton = pygame.image.load("Play Button.png")
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

def playButtonFunction():
    if background == pygame.image.load("Home Screen.png"):
        background.blit(playButton(533.5,278))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            bg = False

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    if bg:
        background = pygame.image.load("Intro Screen.png")
    else:
        background = pygame.image.load("Home Screen.png")
    playButtonFunction()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `if background == pygame.image.load("Home Screen.png")`. I'm pretty sure you cannot compare images that way.

Answer (score 2):

As Frédéric Hamidi already said in a comment, the line

```
if background == pygame.image.load("Home Screen.png")
```

will not work as you probably expect.

You should probabkly pass a flag to that method or don't call that function at all when you don't want to show that `playButton` image.

---

Also, the line

```
background.blit(playButton(533.5,278))
```

will throw an exception, it should look like

```
background.blit(playButton, (533, 278))
```

---

So, change your code to

```
...

if bg:
    background = pygame.image.load("Intro Screen.png")
else:
    background = pygame.image.load("Home Screen.png")

screen.blit(background,(0,0))    
if !bg:
    background.blit(playButton, (533, 278))

...
```

---

Another issue that you load the images from disk every iteration of your game loop (with `pygame.image.load`). It's enough to load each image once.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't entirely understand, so can you please type out the whole code? Thanks again.